# Invited as an expert to/for/on...?

Tags: prepositions

What preposition should be used in this sentence?

> She was invited as an expert [for/to/on/?] this project.

I.e. my goal is not to say that this person is an expert in a certain area, but that she has been invited in this role to participate in some project.

Comment: The meaning you want isn't clear. Is the project this person's area of expertise, or was the person brought into the project as an expert (in something)?

Comment: Generally, you get invited *to* something, *as* an expert *on* a topic.  I think your sentence is a little unclear because the word order is unusual and you end up with the ambiguous "an expert __ this project", whereas if you reordered it as "___ this project as an expert" the answer would be clearer.